# Unix Text Processing - how to remove part of a file name from the results?

Tags: unix, sed, grep, text-processing

I'm searching through text files using grep and sed commands and I also want the file names displayed before my results. However, I'm trying to remove part of the file name when it is displayed.

The file names are formatted like this: aja_EPL_1999_03_01.txt

I want to have only the date without the beginning letters and without the .txt extension.

I've been searching for an answer and it seems like it's possible to do that with a sed or a grep command by using something like this to look forward and back and extract between _ and .txt:

```
(?<=_)\d+(?=\.)
```

But I must be doing something wrong, because it hasn't worked for me and I possibly have to add something as well, so that it doesn't extract only the first number, but the whole date. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Adding also the working command I've used just in case. I imagine whatever command is needed would have to go at the beginning?

```
sed '/^$/d' *.txt | grep -P '(^([A-ZÖÄÜÕŠŽ].*)?[Pp][Aa][Ll]{2}.*[^\.]$)' *.txt --colour -A 1
```

The results look like this:

```
aja_EPL_1999_03_02.txt:PALLILENNUD : korraga üritavad ümbermaailmalendu kaks meeskonda
```

A desired output would be this:

```
1999_03_02:PALLILENNUD : korraga üritavad ümbermaailmalendu kaks meeskonda
```

Comment: Make it explicit what your input is and what the desired output would be.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it right away.

Comment: If your filenames look like `aja_EPL_1999_03_01.txt`, it sounds like you want to pipe the output you have through `sed 's/^[^0-9]*//'` or `grep -o '[0-9].*'`

Comment: @ghoti thanks, that worked, along with sed  's/$*.txt//'. Not sure if it's possible to combine them into one command, but I get the desired result.

Comment: Ok, I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you might want to think about your regular expression. While the one you have you say works, I wonder if it could be simplified. You told us:

```
(^([A-ZÖÄÜÕŠŽ].*)?[Pp][Aa][Ll]{2}.*[^\.]$)
```

It looks to me as if this is intended to match lines that start with a case insensitive "PALL", possibly preceded by any number of other characters that start with a capital letter, and that lines must not end in a backslash or a dot. So valid lines might be any of:

```
PALLILENNUD : korraga üritavad etc etc
Õlu on kena. Do I have appalling speling?
Peeter Pall is a limnologist at EMU!
```

If you'd care to narrow down this description a little and perhaps provide some examples of lines that should be matched or skipped, we may be able to do better. For instance, your outer parentheses are probably unnecessary.

---

Now, let's clarify what your pipe *isn't* doing.

```
sed '/^$/d' *.txt
```

This reads all your .txt files as an input stream, deletes any empty lines, and prints the output to stdout.

```
grep -P 'regex' *.txt --otheroptions
```

This reads all your .txt files, and prints any lines that match `regex`. *It does not read stdin.*

So .. in the command line you're using right now, your sed command is utterly ignored, as sed's output is not being read by grep. You COULD instruct grep to read from both files and stdin:

```
$ echo "hello" > x.txt
$ echo "world" | grep "o" x.txt -
x.txt:hello
(standard input):world
```

But that's not what you're doing.

By default, when `grep` reads from multiple files, it will precede each match with the name of the file from whence that match originated. That's also what you're seeing in my example above -- two inputs, one `x.txt` and the other `-` a.k.a. stdin, separated by a colon from the match they supplied.

While `grep` does include the most minuscule capability for filtering (with `-o`, or GNU grep's `\K` with optional Perl compatible RE), it does NOT provide you with any options for formatting the filename. Since you can'd do anything with the output of `grep`, you're limited to either parsing the output you've got, or using some other tool.

Parsing is easy, if your filenames are predictably structured as they seem to be from the two examples you've provided.

For this, we can ignore that these lines contain a file and data. For the purpose of the filter, they are a *stream* which follows a *pattern*. It looks like you want to strip off all characters from the beginning of each line up to and not including the first digit.  You can do this by piping through sed:

```
sed 's/^[^0-9]*//'
```

Or you can achieve the same effect by using `grep`'s minimal filtering to return every match starting from the first digit:

```
grep -o '[0-9].*'
```

If this kind of pipe-fitting is not to your liking, you may want to replace your entire `grep` with something in `awk` that combines functionality:

```
$ awk '
    /[\.]$/ {next}             # skip lines ending in backslash or dot
    /^([A-ZÖÄÜÕŠŽ].*)?PALL/ {  # lines to match
      f=FILENAME
      sub(/^[^0-9]*/,"",f)     # strip unwanted part of filename, like sed
      printf "%s:%s\n", f, $0
      getline                  # simulate the "-A 1" from grep
      printf "%s:%s\n", f, $0
    }' *.txt
```

Note that I haven't tested this, because I don't have your data to work with.

Also, `awk` doesn't include any of the fancy terminal-dependent colourization that GNU grep provides through the `--colour` option.